# "cryptsetup: ERROR: Couldn't resolve device" combined with "cryptsetup: WARNING: target 'sda3_crypt' not found in /etc/crypttab"

Tags: encryption, swap, initramfs, disk-encryption, cryptsetup

After setting up [hibernation on ubuntu 20.04](https://blog.ivansmirnov.name/how-to-set-up-hibernate-on-ubuntu-20-04/) and modifying it that it works for [encrypted swap partitions](https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/encrypted-swap-partition-on/), I'm getting several issues:

First, after rebooting from hibernation, I got "Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device" along with "Volume group luks not found".
Fortunately, I could boot the system normally afterwards.

Still, when going through the steps of the aforementioned websites again, I get the following errors and warnings when executing `sudo update-initramfs -c -k all`:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-56-generic
cryptsetup: ERROR: Couldn't resolve device 
    /dev/disk/by-uuid/5834cf70-0919-4c53-98a6-355d69bbd6a4
cryptsetup: ERROR: Couldn't resolve device 
    UUID=5834cf70-0919-4c53-98a6-355d69bbd6a4
cryptsetup: WARNING: target 'sda3_crypt' not found in /etc/crypttab
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-58-generic
cryptsetup: ERROR: Couldn't resolve device 
    /dev/disk/by-uuid/5834cf70-0919-4c53-98a6-355d69bbd6a4
cryptsetup: ERROR: Couldn't resolve device 
    UUID=5834cf70-0919-4c53-98a6-355d69bbd6a4
cryptsetup: WARNING: target 'sda3_crypt' not found in /etc/crypttab
```

Note that the `UUID=5834cf70-0919-4c53-98a6-355d69bbd6a4` belonged to the previously non-encrypted swap partition `sda3`.
I replaced this `UUID` with the one of the encrypted partition `sda3_crypt` in every configuration file (see below) I know of.

I hope with the following printouts provided the problems can be resolved.
The contents of the configuration files involved (concerning the swap partition) are:

**1. /etc/fstab**

```
/dev/mapper/sda3_crypt none swap sw 0 0
```

**2. /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume**

```
RESUME=UUID=1e1793ab-315d-4797-a4df-ba5675f4c177
```

**3. /etc/crypttab**

```
sda3_crypt /dev/sda3 /dev/urandom cipher=aes-xts-plain64,size=256,swap,discard
```

**4. /etc/default/grub**

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="cryptdevice=UUID=abcb93a9-b73a-4e57-9f78-91b292b6bfb2:luks-abcb93a9-b73a-4e57-9f78-91b292b6bfb2 root=/dev/mapper/luks-abcb93a9-b73a-4e57-9f78-91b292b6bfb2 resume=UUID=1e1793ab-315d-4797-a4df-ba5675f4c177"
```

**5. cat /proc/swaps**

```
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/dev/dm-1                               partition       16561148        55296   -2
```

**6. free -mh**

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.6Gi       3.6Gi       139Mi       545Mi       3.9Gi       3.2Gi
Swap:          15Gi        54Mi        15Gi
```

**7. sudo swapon --all --verbose**

```
swapon: /dev/mapper/sda3_crypt: already active -- ignored
```

**8. blkid | grep swap**

```
/dev/mapper/sda3_crypt: UUID="1e1793ab-315d-4797-a4df-ba5675f4c177" TYPE="swap"
```

**9. lsblk | grep SWAP**

```
`-sda3_crypt                                253:1    0  15.8G  0 crypt [SWAP]
```

The entire printouts of all mounted devices:

```
~/$ blkid
/dev/mapper/luks-abcb93a9-b73a-4e57-9f78-91b292b6bfb2: UUID="3dad5211-99f3-4513-bbcc-de820c2dbe8b" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda1: UUID="11F5-FCE6" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="59397319-bfe7-1841-b259-c157e97b19bd"
/dev/sda2: UUID="abcb93a9-b73a-4e57-9f78-91b292b6bfb2" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="11c68a93-8cdf-e04f-ad0d-d4c1bfce2796"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/mapper/sda3_crypt: UUID="1e1793ab-315d-4797-a4df-ba5675f4c177" TYPE="swap"

~/$ lsblk
NAME                                          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
loop0                                           7:0    0  55.4M  1 loop  /snap/core18/1932
loop1                                           7:1    0  55.4M  1 loop  /snap/core18/1944
loop2                                           7:2    0  31.1M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/10238
loop3                                           7:3    0  31.1M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/10492
sda                                             8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk  
|-sda1                                          8:1    0   300M  0 part  /boot/efi
|-sda2                                          8:2    0 216.8G  0 part  
| `-luks-abcb93a9-b73a-4e57-9f78-91b292b6bfb2 253:0    0 216.8G  0 crypt /
`-sda3                                          8:3    0  15.8G  0 part  
  `-sda3_crypt                                253:1    0  15.8G  0 crypt [SWAP]
```

Answer (score 2):

Do all the lines in all your config files end with the newline character?

I encountered the below error while running `update-initramfs -c -k all`:

```
cryptsetup: WARNING: target 'sda4_crypt' not found in /etc/crypttab
```

My `/etc/crypttab` was:

```
sda4_crypt UUID=[snip] none luks,discard
```

However, there was no newline character at the end of the line.  `/etc/crypttab` was generated by a POSIX shell script (a script that I wrote), and it is hideously difficult create variables with trailing newline characters in POSIX shell.

After I added a newline character at the end of the line, the error message went away, and it appears that `initramfs` is now running successfully.

Comment: > hideously difficult  - perhaps: echo "sda4_crypt UUID=[$uuid] none luks,discard" or printf "%s%d_crypt UUID=[%s] none luks,discard\n" "$disk" "$part" "$uuid"

Comment: I only want to rewrite the file if it needs to change.  So... I store the desired text in a variable (including the trailing newline).  I read the actual text from the file (including the trailing newline, if one exists).  Then, I only update (rewrite) the file if the desired and actual text differ.  In POSIX shell, creating and/or preserving trailing newlines is far more work than it should be.

Comment: How can I check whether all lines in these textfiles have an endline character?

Comment: I can tell by examining the files in my text editor.  I use emacs and jed.  You could also run `cat filename ; echo xxx` in a terminal, and see if the `xxx` appears at the beginning versus the end of the line.

Comment: `cat -vte filename ; echo xxx` would show any control chars, tabs, and end-of-line.

Comment: I'm bookmarking this for the next time someone asks why it's so important to add newlines to EOF.